# Using layer file to apply symbology to shapefile with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, symbology, layers, error-000732

I have code that doesn't work at the moment:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Input == '#' or not Input:
    Input = "frame" # provide a default value if unspecified

Symbology = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Symbology == '#' or not Symbology:
    Symbology = "symbology" # provide a default value if unspecified


### Local variables:
Rearrange = Symbology
line_connection_shp = Rearrange
### Process: Apply Symbology From Layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(Input, Symbology)
Process: Points To Line
arcpy.PointsToLine_management(Rearrange, line_connection_shp, "MMSI", "", "NO_CLOSE")
```

What this is doing is applying my layer symbology (a .lyr file) to a shapefile.

This results in an error:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset C:\temp\test.shp does not exist or is not supported.
```

It works fine when I apply these tools myself, but creates errors while using it in Python.

This must be an issue with trying to input a shapefile into the ApplyFromSymbology tool, so is there a way to use a shapefile with that tool?

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing the code required to add a layer to the map at all.

You need a feature layer from the shapefile and then save it on disk as the .lyr file.

```
inputLocationsSavedFcFeatLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_locations_fc,"Stops")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_layer=inputLocationsSavedFcFeatLyr,
                                     out_layer=r"C:\GIS\LocationPoints1.lyr",
                                     is_relative_path=None,version=None)
```

Specify the template layer (with symbology you want to be applied) + apply it:

```
locationsTemplate_layer = mp.Layer(r"C:\GIS\LocationPoints1.lyr")
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(locationsTemplate_layer,r"C:\GIS\LocationPointsTemplate.lyr")
```

Now you can add the .lyr file to the map document (here, it is added to a group layer):

```
mp.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, locationsTemplate_layer)
```

More help docs on that is here:

- [Layer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/)
- [AddLayer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000025000000.)